# New lines in EOF multiline text produce errors in sed command using Unix shell

Tags: shell, sed

Here my run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

before=$(cat <<EOF
require SYSPATH.'core/Bootstrap'.EXT;
EOF
)

after=$(cat <<EOF
if(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'phpunit'){
sometext # <= without it works fine!
EOF
)

sed -i.bak "s|$before|$after|g" "$2"
```

## error

sed: -e expression #1, char 79: unterminated `s' command

## Works fine but I want replace multiline text!

```
#!/bin/sh

before=$(cat <<EOF
require SYSPATH.'core/Bootstrap'.EXT;
EOF
)

after=$(cat <<EOF
if(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'phpunit'){
EOF
)

sed -i.bak "s|$before|$after|g" "$2"
```

Comment: You probably want `cat << 'EOF'` instead of `cat << EOF` if you don't want `$_SERVERS` to be expanded to the content of the `$_SERVERS` shell variable.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'phpunit'){ \n \ # <= BACKSLASH needed!
sometext
```